# How can I convert a currency string to a number ignoring separators?

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I have a `NumberFormatter` (called `currencyFormatter`) which is configured to convert a `String`, such as "£1,000" to the `NSDecimalNumber` 1000 using the following code:

```
// Configuration
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.currencyCode = "GBP"

// Usage
currencyFormatter.number(from: "£1,000")
```

If I omit the commas from the string the conversion still works but, if the commas as misplaced ("£10,00" for example), the method fails, returning nil.

While I could remove all the commas, this would cause issues in locales which use a comma as the decimal separator and the period in place of the comma.

Is there a safe way I can loosen the requirements of the thousands-separator (commas, periods or whatever character any other currency might use) placement in the `NumberFormatter` slightly but without allowing unreasonable conversion?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you obtain the currency string? It comes from BE always having the same format? Or is it somehow obtained interacting with Device?

Comment: So you would like "£10,00" to be interpreted as "£1,000"? What about removing the formatter's `currencyGroupingSeparator` instead of a hard-coded comma?

Comment: @OlegDanu I'm trying to allow a textField be a bit more friendly to the user, so if they want to make this value ten times higher, they can just add a zero on the end and not worry about where the commas are.

Comment: @JoshParadroid, then just don't use grouping separators

Comment: @MartinR I think yours is most reasonable suggestion. I guess I was concerned that there could be other currencies that might have even more complicated formatting, but I can't think of any. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll tick it. Thanks.

Comment: @user28434 Currency is easier to read with them.

Comment: @JoshParadroid, yes, but `easier reading` is irrelevant during parsing, you would have to strip them in that case. Because now those comas mean nothing.

Comment: @user28434 Oh right. I agree. I misunderstood your previous comment. I interpreted it as suggesting I don't use them at all whereas I think you're suggesting I strip them from the string to be parsed. Sorry.

Comment: @JoshParadroid, lil offtopic comment: it looks like you're working with currency/finances, so make sure this fix in parsing won't cause any damage to your clients, maybe allow them to double check how your app parsed their input, or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to be lenient on the placements of the grouping
separator (which can be a comma or a period, depending on the locale)
then you could remove the formatters `currencyGroupingSeparator` 
from the input string instead of a hard-coded comma:

```
var input = "£10,00"
if let sep = currencyFormatter.currencyGroupingSeparator {
    input = input.replacingOccurrences(of: sep, with: "")
}
```

Comment: That's exactly my intention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace currencyGroupingSeparator with ""  and instead static

```
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = "£"

    print("number == \(currencyFormatter.number(from: "£10.00,56".replacingOccurrences(of: currencyFormatter.currencyGroupingSeparator, with: "")))")
   //it will print as 1000.56
```